# How to prevent vagrant from asking ssh key passphrase

Tags: ssh, vagrant, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Everything works fine, but it keeps prompting for ssh passphrase during provisioning, which is very annoying, when you have 6 vm's it will prompt you like 12 times (and the whole automation piece kinda loses its point).

I've tried searching the web, but couldn't find an answer to a pretty obvious question.

Comment: I have never had this happen. Could you explain how you were able to make Vagrant prompt for a ssh passphrase? I am legitimately curious.

Comment: install it, supply key with passphrase and your good

Comment: I shoulda probably said that I'm using bash for windows to run vagrant @MattSchuchard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways how to prevent this.

- First of all and most obvious (but least preferable) is to remove the passphrase from the key:

  ```
  ssh-keygen -p -P old_passphrase -N "" -f /path/to/key_file
  ```
- The other possibility is to use `ssh-agent`, which will store the encrypted version of your key and will do the required operation on it when asked. You can find many guides and questions about it, but for completeness

  ```
  eval $(ssh-agent)
  ssh-add /path/to/key_file
  do-your-vagrant-stuff
  ```
- You can use `sshpass`, which will provide the passphrase to the `ssh` commands. It can read the passphrase as an argument, from environment variable or from file (can be insecure)

  ```
  sshpass -p password your-vagrant-stuff
  ```

there are probably other ways, but you should most probably use `ssh-agent`.

Comment: thanks, let me investigate if this works, and I'll get back to you promptly.